# openssl structures has been made opaque in openssl-1.1.1

Tags: openssl, c, ssl, cryptography, open-source

In case, we need to zeroize those structure members in place, how do we handle it ? Currently API are there to get and set those structure members. But to zeroize in place , are there any API ? eg: DH structure

And how to retrieve members of X509_EXTENSION structure members in latest openssl (i.e.,) members of "ASN1_OCTET_STRING" ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?